# Insert into saving data double

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server

I am trying to save data by method on client side. But when i check db table every time saved double.

I have tried everything but can not solve the problem.

Client side

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strName;     
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelCountry;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelCity;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@County", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelCounty;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Town", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelTown;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@District", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelDistrict;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Km", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelKm;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Min", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelMin;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Direction", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelDirection;
     if (intId == 0)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tabl_Hotels (fldName,fldCountry,fldCity,fldCounty,fldTown,fldDistrict,fldKm,fldMin,fldDirection) VALUES (@Name,@Country,@City,@County,@Town,@District,@Km,@Min,@Direction);";
    try
    {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Bootstrap.Success("Hotel saved successfully.");     
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Bootstrap.Danger(ex.Message); }       
    Response.End();
    }
```

html button

```
 <button type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary" data-webmethod="hotels.aspx/save" >Save</button>
```

java script

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btn-save', function(e) {
        var HotelName = document.getElementById('<%= HotelNameTextBox.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelCountry= document.getElementById('<%= HotelCountryDropDownList.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelCity=document.getElementById('<%= HotelCityDropDownList.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelCounty=document.getElementById('<%= HotelCountyDropDownList.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelTown=document.getElementById('<%= HotelTownDropDownList.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelDistrict=document.getElementById('<%= HotelDistrictDropDownList.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelDistancek=document.getElementById('<%= HotelDistancekTextBox.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelDistancem=document.getElementById('<%= HotelDistancehTextBox.ClientID %>').value,
            HotelDirection=document.getElementById('<%= HotelDirectionDropDownList.ClientID %>').value;

        if(HotelDistancem=="" || HotelDistancek=="" || HotelName=="" || HotelCountry==0 || HotelCity==0 || HotelCounty==0 || HotelTown==0 || HotelDistrict==0 || HotelDirection==0){ bootbox.alert('Do not leave any blank.!');return false;}
        alert('deneme');
        });
```

Comment: your problem is not at all clear

Comment: It sounds like your button is bound with click event twice or somehow you are sending data twice. check if that's the case

Comment: your **insert** query executed double. you can use **debugger** in your javascript code for check

Comment: @Yeou I put alert on JavaScript side and getting one alert. Also In client side i got one success message.

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi impossible. I am adding this codes on plesk

Comment: Use the profiler from SSMS to see how many times the insert gets send to the database. My bet is that it gets send 2 times. If it gets send 2 times, than you know that your app is sending it 2 times somehow, if not, then you have to check your database for triggers or someting

Comment: @SemihCanBilgen The code above looks fine. However, the fact stand as is. The code is being executed twice that is for sure. You need to check it. maybe you bound the button with some other event which is being called or check server side code. The code you provided is not enought for us to provide you with proper answer.

Comment: @Yeou You were right. When i write Bootbox Alert on client side, I got twice alert. And when ı check project I gave double ref for <script src="client-side/js/webmethod.js"></script> one of is on Master page other is Hotels page. so double webmethod double save. I solved

Comment: @SemihCanBilgen great. That's nice.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with a break point and debug the code. Code might not have the ispostback validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have to add this codes on plesk. So i can not debug.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. I give double reference for web-method one of in Master page other is ON web page.  so when i use save method it run twice. I delete reference from page and the problem solved.

```
     <script src="client-side/js/webmethod.js"></script>
```